# Angularjs Filter with single key multiple values of parent data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm very new in Angularjs. We can filter by multiple key value but here I need to filter by single value but my parent data containing multiple values.
Like

In Controller:

```
$scope.movies = [{name:'aa', criteria:'SECURITY TYPE:Stocks|GEOGRAPHY:US'},
                  {name:'bb', criteria:'TRADING STRATEGY:Monthly|YIELD:Mid,Blend'},
                  {name:'cc', criteria:'SECURITY TYPE:Stocks|YIELD:Mid,Blend'},
                  {name:'dd', criteria:'MARKETCAPITALIZATION:Mega|VOLATILITY:Low'}];


$scope.filterByProperties = function (data) {

 return $scope.filter[data.criteria] || noSubFilter($scope.filter);

};

function noSubFilter(subFilterObj) {
        for (var key in subFilterObj) {
            if (subFilterObj[key]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In View file:

```
<label>SECURITY TYPE</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter['Stocks']"> Stocks

<label>Yield</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter['Mid']"> Mid
```

But as the data.criteria field containing multiple values how will I filter them  from checkbox?

Comment: The value of "criteria" is a string. Seems like you are threating it as an object

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom filter to filter out the data.

```
<label>SECURITY TYPE</label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="criteria.stocks"> Stocks</input>

  <label>Yield</label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="criteria.mids"> Mid</input>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="m in movies | typeFilter: criteria">
      {{m.name}} {{m.criteria}}

    </li>
```

add the filter

```
.filter('typeFilter', function($filter) {
   return function(input, criteria) {
console.log(criteria);
console.log(input);
var data = input;
if(criteria && !criteria.mids && !criteria.stocks){
  return input;
}
if(criteria.stocks){
  console.log(data);
    data = $filter('filter')( data, {criteria:'Stocks'} );
    console.log(data);
}
if(criteria.mids){
  console.log(data);
  data = $filter('filter')(data, {criteria:'Mid'} );
  console.log(data);
}
return data;}});
```

I've created a working example here http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/wGOKJo

Comment: Here the list of checkbox is long.. its not a good idea to use such long list of filter objects.

Comment: You might try creating a custom filter and use lodash to identify if the object contains the value or not.  I've updated my codepen to show how to create a custom filter.  Rather than use lodash I'm just using the built in $filter.  This is just to show how to use the custom filter then you can make the filtering logic most efficient for your situation.